# XSLT: Date Format to Long Date

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, xslt-1.0

I am working on some XSL for a PDF that I believe uses an engine, FOP. At the moment I am trying to display a date format from MM/dd/yyyy to a long date (Jan 1 , 1990)

The XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
 <cf_customer_quotation_expiration_date type="date">2014-11-08</cf_customer_quotation_expiration_date>
</hash>
```

The XSL contains the following code by default: (This is what I want to change in order to output the long date from the above short date)

```
<fo:block text-align="right">
    <xsl:call-template name="date:format-iso8601-date">
        <xsl:with-param name="iso8601-date">
            <xsl:value-of select="/hash/cf_customer_quotation_expiration_date" />
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</fo:block>
```

And in case anyone is interested in the stylesheet formatters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xslt:stylesheet xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xc="http://www.ecrion.com/2008/xc" xmlns:xf="http://www.ecrion.com/xf/1.0" xmlns:xfd="http://www.ecrion.com/xfd/1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="date str">
    <xslt:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">



    <xslt:template name="date:format-iso8601-date">
        <xslt:param name="iso8601-date" />
        <xslt:variable name="format">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/hash/text/Date_Format != &quot;&quot;">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/hash/text/Date_Format" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>"dd/MM/yyyy"</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xslt:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$format = &quot;yyyy-MM-dd&quot;">
                <xsl:value-of select="$iso8601-date" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$format = &quot;MM/dd/yyyy&quot;">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($iso8601-date, 6, 2)" />
                /
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($iso8601-date, 9, 2)" />
                /
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($iso8601-date, 1, 4)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Default to dd/MM/yyyy -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($iso8601-date, 9, 2)" />
                /
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($iso8601-date, 6, 2)" />
                /
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($iso8601-date, 1, 4)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xslt:template>
</xslt:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*from MM/dd/yyyy to a long date (Jan 1 , 1990)*" Your input seems to be YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Ah yes my input is yyyy-mm-dd. I am wondering how do I show a long date in my XSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template name="format-Date">
    <xsl:param name="iso8601-date"/>

    <xsl:param name="yyyy" select="substring($iso8601-date, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:param name="mm" select="substring($iso8601-date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:param name="dd" select="substring($iso8601-date, 9, 2)"/>

    <xsl:param name="mmm" select="substring('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 3 * ($mm - 1) + 1, 3)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($mmm, ' ', number($dd), ', ', $yyyy)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I could add this, but I assume this would overwrite any other date I may use on my sheet. Is there a way I can keep both formats of dates and call the template when ever I need?

Comment: never mind, I was not thinking when I posted that. Thanks for the help the code works.